# why can't I catch these errors?

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs

I'm writing a test suite for a library, and trying to repeat a pattern I have used literally everywhere else in order to test for the errors it should throw. For example, in another test suite I have the following code (which works perfectly):

```
const fun = rawFileDownloaderFactory(fetch)(noop);
await expect(() => fun(t)).rejects.toThrow(new NoDirectoryAccessError(badDir));
```

I am now testing to see if my function throws when it can't write to a file (this is a different part of the library) but somehow the error gets thrown *outside* any of the error handling logic. In order to get to the bottom of this I wrote the following harness:

```
const fun = datafileWriterFactory(fetch)(selector, parser)(noop);
try {
  console.log("START");
  await (
    fun(t)
    .then(() => console.log("WORKED"))
    .catch((e) => console.error("FAILED", e))
  );
} catch(e) {
  console.error("This should have been caught before", e);
} finally {
  console.log("FINISH");
}
await expect(() => fun(t)).rejects.toThrow();
```

I'm using `jest` as my test runner, and when I run this test I get the following output:

```
● Console

    console.log
      START

      at Object.<anonymous> (lib/sinks/datafile_writer_factory.test.ts:256:15)

  ● datafileWriterFactory creates a Sink which › throws when it cannot write to the file

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/knobble-test-FHlzW9-not/addresses.json'
```

I would have expected, however, at least one of the error handling methods to work (either try ... catch or Promise.catch).

Why might these errors (being thrown by `fs.createWriteStream`) not be caught properly within jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code doesn't execute your catch block nor the `catch` callback because the `fs.createWriteStream` method returns a `WritableStream` instead of a `Promise` which resolves to the `WritableStream`.

This means that you'd need to listen for an `error` event instead of trying to handle a Promise rejection or catch an error.

I've tried this in the console to confirm:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

let writeStream;

try {
  writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("/test.txt");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("not logged", e);
}

writeStream.on("error", (e) => console.log("logged", e));
```

Assuming I can't write to `/test.txt`, for example, I get:

```js
$ node repro.js

logged { [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/test.txt'] errno: -30, code: 'EROFS', syscall: 'open', path: '/test.txt' }
```

Comment: You were right, adding a `.on("error", ...)` fixed it.